# woocommerce pdf invoice - Orders paid by prepaid balance and credit card are not sending pdf invoice

Tags: email, woocommerce, payment, invoice

our websites works very well for like several years but recently some customers raised that they only received the confirmation email but not the invoice email after purchase a product.

These customers are all paid via Prepaid Balance and Credit Card. And all customers paid by Invoice are all succeed and received their pdf invoice. I have checked the backend and found the pdf was all generated just not sent.

Also in edit the order page, there is a box next to order details have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsSpA.png)

Does anyone know the possible reason which could cause the pdf invocie not sending?

Please let me know if you need more information, and we will be really appreciate if you could help us sort it out. Thank you

Comment: Which plugin do you use to send the PDF invoice?

Comment: @Mr.Jo This one https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices/

Comment: Awesome! Have you already asked the plugin support? I think this would be the best idea since I don't know this plugin. If you find the code in the plugin which checks the payment type I might can help you!

Comment: yes yes I did send this issue to their support team last Friday and haven't got the reply yet. But you are right, I should double check their plugin. Also we have a dev site which is 100% same as the live site and that one works pretty good so I'm considering maybe it's related to sendgrid or some other issue. Hope I can get some reply from the support team! thanks